# How to get list of Facebook pages managed by a user

Tags: ios, facebook

I am currently doing an app, in which I need to make the user select one of the Facebook pages from the list of facebook pages the user manages.

I searched and found that, we are able to search the pages by name, but that includes the whole pages in Facebook. I just need the pages that I manage.

**Update**:

I gave the /me/accounts for getting the pages that I manage. But the resulting data that i get is

2014-05-14 10:22:11.519 fb page[1695:60b] {
    data =     (
    );
}

Here is my code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/accounts"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {

                          if (!error)
                          {
                              NSLog(@"%@",result);
                              NSDictionary *dict = result;
                              pagesArray = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
                              NSLog(@"%uld", pagesArray.count);
                              if (pagesArray.count  == 0)
                              {
                                  UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No pages Found" message:@"You do not manage any pages" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                  [alert show];
                                  [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                              }
                              else{

                              facebookPageId = [[pagesArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"];
                              NSLog(@"%@", facebookPageId);
                              [self getPage];
                              [self getPagePosts];
                              }
                          }
                          else

                              NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

I also gave the login permission, like this:

```
self.loginView.publishPermissions = @[@"manage_pages"];
```

I also get this warning:

FBSDKLog: FBSession: a permission request for publish or manage permissions contains unexpected read permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/accounts/).

```
/{user-id}/accounts
```

returns Facebook pages of which the current user is an admin.

A user access token with `manage_pages` permission is required, and will only allow the retrieval for that specific person.

You can also try:

```
/{user-id}/applications/developer/
```

to get list of apps managed by the user.

Comment: You can also try `/me/applications/developer/`. For me, it returned all my managed pages.

Comment: thanx reecon, but, the thing is do we need to set any permissions for that. I had used the /me/accounts and it returns empty. I dont understand. I have 4 pages that i manage, and how come it turns nothing? Please help dude.

Comment: me/applications/developers/ returns all the apps that i manage. they are not pages

Comment: A user access token with `manage_pages` permission is required, and will only allow the retrieval for that specific person.